# Curved Text in Fabric JS

Tags: fabricjs

I am facing this error, when i have curved text and svg in canvas while using fabricjs 2.0.3

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromObject' of undefined"

Comment: What is the class name for curved text?

Comment: fabric.CurvedText

Comment: Its still not implemented yet right? which one you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText

This is the library I am using for curved text currently, however there is no indication that this library is not supporting the current version of fabric.